# When I use this .htaccess code then it's source URL is returning a 404, Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, custom-wordpress-pages

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name1=([^&]+)&name2=([^&]+)$
    RewriteRule ^$ /%1-vs-%2? [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I use this .thaccess code then i get this type of link https://example.com/5paisa-vs-abhipra-capital but problem is when i get this url then it's showing this error "The source URL is returning a 404" so, how to fix this error?

Comment: There's not enough information here... with what you have posted it looks like the `.htaccess` code is working "fine" and your PHP application is returning "The source URL is returning a 404" (since that's not a normal Apache response). "When I use this .thaccess code then i get this type of link" - the `.htaccess` code does not change the links, that is determined by your PHP code. And you've spelt ".thaccess" wrong (which could also be the cause of your error).